# how to format date string for x axis labels in chartjs?

Tags: php, jquery, chart.js

I have recently worked on time scale chart from `chart.js`. but now i want to labels in `data` like 01-02-2017, 02-06-2017 instead of "4 February 2017", "9 February 2017" and so on.

**Here my code**

```
var aR = null;  //store already returned tick
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'line',
   data: {
           /* labels: ["01-01-2017", "03-01-2017", "04-02-2017", "09-02-2017", "03-03-2017", "17-03-2017","23-03-2017","09-04-2017"],*/

      labels: ["1 January 2017", "3 January 2017","12 January 2017","20 January 2017","22 January 2017","23 January 2017","27 January 2017", "4 February 2017", "9 February 2017", "3 March 2017", "17 March 2017","23 March 2017","15 March 2017"],
      datasets: [{
         label: "My First dataset",
         backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)',
         borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
         data: [12, 16, 2, 7, 15, 5, 11, 10, 11, 1, 8, 9, 15],
         lineTension: 0
      }]
   },
   options: {
      scales: {
         xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
               autoSkip: false,
               callback: function(e) {
                  var tick = e.match(/(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sept|Oct|Nov|Dec).*?\d+/g)[0];
                  if (tick != aR) {
                     aR = tick;
                     return tick;
                  }
               }
            }
         }],
         yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
               min: 0,
               max: 30
            }
         }]
      }
   }
});
```

So how can i relabeled their labels. kindly guide me. Thanks..

Comment: you want to display like `01-02-2017, 02-06-2017` this?

Comment: Why labels are hardcoded?

Comment: Make labels are dynamic and in this format 'labels: ["01-01-2017", "03-01-2017", "04-02-2017", "09-02-2017", "03-03-2017", "17-03-2017","23-03-2017","09-04-2017"]'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming, you wish to show the x-axis labels as `01 January 2017` not as `01-01-2017` .

If that's the case then, you need to re-format your date string, which you could accomplish in the following way ...

```js
var date_arr = ["01-01-2017", "03-01-2017", "04-02-2017", "09-02-2017", "03-03-2017", "17-03-2017", "23-03-2017", "09-04-2017"];

var labels = formatDate(date_arr);

function formatDate(arr) {
   var new_date = [];
   arr.forEach(function(d) {
      var date = d.split('-')[0].replace(/\d+/, function(e) {
         switch (e) {
            case '01': case '21': case '31':
               return e + 'st';
            case '02': case '22':
               return e + 'nd';
            case '03': case '23':
               return e + 'rd';
            default:
               return e + 'th';
         }
      });
      var month = new Date(d.split('-')[1]).toLocaleString('en-us', {
         month: "long"
      });
      var year = d.split('-')[2];
      new_date.push(date + ' ' + month + ' ' + year);
   });
   return new_date;
}

/*** GENERATE CHART ****/

var aR = null; //store already returned tick
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'line',
   data: {
      labels: labels,
      datasets: [{
         label: "My First dataset",
         backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)',
         borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
         data: [12, 16, 10, 11, 9, 15, 13, 16],
         lineTension: 0
      }]
   },
   options: {
      scales: {
         xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
               autoSkip: false,
               callback: function(e) {
                  var tick = e.match(/(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sept|Oct|Nov|Dec).*?\d+/g)[0];
                  if (tick != aR) {
                     aR = tick;
                     return tick;
                  }
               }
            }
         }],
         yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
               min: 0,
               max: 30
            }
         }]
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<canvas id="myChart" height="200"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yeah..! you make my day. Thanks :)